# Is there any way to save API response as a file to local computer disk

Tags: sql, api, ssrs-2008, data-warehouse, dotnet-httpclient

Not very familiar with API, and did't got much help on this in internet.

I am creating some reports using SQL queries and SSRS. Most applications have SQL server as its database, but one application provides API interface only. I am trying this data also get downloaded to an on-premise SQL Server database for making reports.

Currently, to see the data, I have to download and use a HTTP Client tool. I used [Postman](https://blog.getpostman.com/) to create authorization token and can see data in Jason format appears in Postman console using GET request.

But I need this data as a file (preferably CSV) get downloaded on a daily basis to a local folder and so I can push this to SQL Server easily.

Is there any way to accomplish this response get saved as file? Trying to avoid third party tool for automating this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid installing any additional software and you're on a Windows machine, you could use PowerShell to automate this for you.

The Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet sends HTTP and HTTPS requests to a web page or web service. It parses the response and returns collections of links, images, and other significant HTML elements. This cmdlet was introduced in PowerShell 3.0.

Here's an example script to possibly get you started:

```
$url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Get
$response.Content | Out-File -FilePath .\ResponseContent.json
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. But an authorization problem is: first I need to generate a token using POST method using user name and password.
Then need to use that token in subsequent GET request to fetch data.

Comment: The Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet allows you to send Post requests and configure the headers and body that you send along with your Post request.

Take a look at the examples in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6).

Comment: You should be able to send the same Post request that you're sending through Postman to get your token, and then store that in a variable that you can pass to the subsequent Get requests.